# How can I simplify this term?

Tags: analysis, functions

How do I get from:

$\dfrac{3x\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\left(x^2-1\right)^\frac{3}{2}}-\dfrac{3x\left(x^2+1\right)^\frac{3}{2}}{\left(x^2-1\right)^\frac{5}{2}}$

To:

$-\dfrac{6x\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\left(x^2-1\right)^\frac{5}{2}}$

Comment: Find the common denominator and subtract them like any other fraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a new solution. It is posted just to further detail the answer by @Henry Lee given to this question:

Given:

$$\frac{3x\sqrt{x^2+1}}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}-\frac{3x(x^2+1)^{3/2}}{(x^2-1)^{5/2}}$$

The main step here is to multiply both fractions by $(x^2-1)^{5/2}$ (common denominator):

$$\frac{3x(x^2+1)^{1/2}(x^2-1)^{(5/2-3/2)}-3x(x^2+1)^{3/2}}{(x^2-1)^{5/2}}$$

The rest is as the shown solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{3x\sqrt{x^2+1}}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}-\frac{3x(x^2+1)^{3/2}}{(x^2-1)^{5/2}}=\frac{3x(x^2+1)^{1/2}(x^2-1)-3x(x^2+1)^{3/2}}{(x^2-1)^{5/2}}$$
$$=\frac{3x(x^2+1)^{1/2}}{(x^2-1)^{5/2}}\times\left[(x^2-1)-(x^2+1)\right]$$
You should be able to do it from here